Ограничение времени работы программы
Я пытаюсь сделать проект, в котором человек должен угадывать 5 чисел в течении 2 минут. ПО истечении 2 минут игра должна прекращаться, но у меня при использовании sleep() останавливается вся программа. Что мне делать, используя только блок time?
проблема в:
for i in range(Minute):
    Minute -= 1
    sleep(1)

from time import *
from random import *

print("Правила:")
print("1. Используйте полноэкранный режим.")
print("2. Введите числа и если они будут верны вы получите секрет.")
print("3. Отсчёт времени начинается с начала ввода данных (всего 2 минуты).")

RandNum1 = randint(0,9)
RandNum2 = randint(0,9)
RandNum3 = randint(0,9)
RandNum4 = randint(0,9)
RandNum5 = randint(0,9)

InNum1 = int(input("Введите первое число"))
InNum2 = int(input("Введите второе число"))
InNum3 = int(input("Введите третье число"))
InNum4 = int(input("Введите четвёртое число"))
InNum5 = int(input("Введите пятое число"))

Minute = 120

while Minute != 0:
    if InNum1 == RandNum1:
        print('1 верно')
    if InNum2 == RandNum2:
        print('2 верно')
    if InNum3 == RandNum3:
        print('3 верно')
    if InNum4 == RandNum4:
        print('4 верно')
    if InNum5 == RandNum5:
        print('5 верно')
    
    timing = time()

    for i in range(Minute):
        Minute -= 1
        sleep(1)

    if InNum1 == RandNum1 and InNum2 == RandNum2 and InNum3 == RandNum3 and InNum4 == RandNum4 and InNum5 == RandNum5: 
        print("ACCESS ALLOWED")
        print("SECRET_MASSAGE:")
        print("000000000000000")

    InNum1 = int(input("Введите первое число"))
    InNum2 = int(input("Введите второе число"))
    InNum3 = int(input("Введите третье число"))
    InNum4 = int(input("Введите четвёртое число"))
    InNum5 = int(input("Введите пятое число"))


У Вас получается, что даже если пользователь отгадает все пять чисел, то цикл будет ожидать окончания таймера. По логике, надо предусмотреть выход из цикла при отгадывании всех чисел.

Спасибо, Вы очень помогли!

Считаю, что первый пример, который описал Amgarak является верным, так как в условии задачи сказано "используя только блок time". Однако, напишу ответ с асинхронностью/многопоточностью, который закроет программу по истечении времени, даже если пользователь не ввел данные.
from random import *
import asyncio
import os

def game():

    print("Правила:")
    print("1. Используйте полноэкранный режим.")
    print("2. Введите числа и если они будут верны вы получите секрет.")
    print("3. Отсчёт времени начинается с начала ввода данных (всего 2 минуты).")

    RandNum1 = randint(0, 9)
    RandNum2 = randint(0, 9)
    RandNum3 = randint(0, 9)
    RandNum4 = randint(0, 9)
    RandNum5 = randint(0, 9)

    while True:

        InNum1 = int(input("Введите первое число"))
        InNum2 = int(input("Введите второе число"))
        InNum3 = int(input("Введите третье число"))
        InNum4 = int(input("Введите четвёртое число"))
        InNum5 = int(input("Введите пятое число"))

        if InNum1 == RandNum1:
            print('1 верно')
        if InNum2 == RandNum2:
            print('2 верно')
        if InNum3 == RandNum3:
            print('3 верно')
        if InNum4 == RandNum4:
            print('4 верно')
        if InNum5 == RandNum5:
            print('5 верно')

        if InNum1 == RandNum1 and InNum2 == RandNum2 and InNum3 == RandNum3 and InNum4 == RandNum4 and InNum5 == RandNum5:
            print("ACCESS ALLOWED")
            print("SECRET_MASSAGE:")
            print("000000000000000")
            os._exit(0)

async def timer(timer_time):
    await asyncio.sleep(timer_time)
    print('\nВремя вышло')
    os._exit(0)

async def main():
    timer_time = 120
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(game))
        tg.create_task(timer(timer_time))

asyncio.run(main())


Вот простой пример, цикл будет крутится ~нужное время:
import time

start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < 120:  # Пока прошло менее 2 минут (120 секунд)
    # Что-то делаем

Второй пример:
import sys
import select

print("Где детонатор?! У тебя 5 секунд:")

rlist, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 5)

if rlist:
    user_input = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    print(f"Детонатор спрятан: {user_input}")
else:
    print("Бабах! 1.")


Позволю себе комментарий, что такой подход, хоть и решает проблему, но является компромиссным - задумавшийся над инпутами пользователь никогда не получит сообщение о том, что время истекло. Мне кажется, что решить такое без применения дополнительных потоков невозможно.

@AlexeyTrukhanov согласен с вашим замечанием, но всё же думаю можно обойтись без дополнительных потоков. Дополнил ответ.

Круто! Не знал про select, спасибо!
